# Запрет на выход PictureBox за определенные рамки без использования Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, обработка-изображений

Недавно, делая программу на C# WindowsForms, я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: машинка должна ездить **только** по дороге и не выезжать за её пределы. Моя карта выглядит [очень заковыристо](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7TBiHRLnSc0RmF6M0pvanJadVk/view?usp=sharing), и использование Panel в данном случае очень затруднительно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нет ли других способов ограничить передвижение PictureBox'а (то есть машинки)

Вот мой код для движения влево:

```
case 37://влево
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - 2, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users/Daniil_2/Desktop/car2.png");
    if (pictureBox1.Left <= 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 2, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
    }
    if (pictureBox1.Left <= panel2.Location.X + panel2.ClientSize.Width)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Location.Y+32 > panel2.Location.Y)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Location.Y < panel2.Location.Y + panel2.ClientSize.Height)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 2, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Но, к сожалению, хоть с одной панелью он и работает, то с 17-ю происходит путаница... Да и времени много тратится...

Comment: Можно ли попросить вместо замечательной картинки с названием языка C#, в ваш вопрос добавить хотя бы схему (иерархию) компонент вашего приложения?
Например, у меня есть форма, на форме рисуется карта в компоненте `Panel`, поверх панели объекты карты сделаны в виде множества `PictureBox`, дорога, по которой должна ездить машинка (`PictureBox`) сделана при помощи компонента хххх.
А еще примеры кода были бы не лишними.

Comment: Уточнение: дополнения, пожалуйста, вносите в оригинальный вопрос (править) а не в ответ.

Comment: Уточняющие вопросы, если не трудно: 1. Что на панели panel2? 2. В вопросе упоминается 17 панелей, а что делают они?

Comment: Конечно... Пройди по ссылке в вопросе- будет показана моя карта. Там на областях, куда нельзя заезжать, находятся Panel'и.

Comment: С другими панелями у меня аналогично...

Comment: Карту я видел, конечно. Попробуем с другой стороны зайти - дорога при помощи чего сделана?

Comment: Все в Paint.NET нарисовано... Это не PrtSc...

Comment: А ты предлагаешь разместить Panel'и на дороге?

Comment: Я пока ничего не предлагаю, я пока хочу понять как именно сделано. И это не важно, в чем нарисовано, хоть на бумажке, а потом отсканировано. :-) На форме в программе дорога при помощи чего сделана? Просто на форме лежит PictureBox, в который загружена картинка карты, а поверх PictureBox с картой - панели для непроходимых мест?

Comment: Да, ты угадал...

Comment: Тогда спустя некоторое время я постараюсь дать развернутый ответ, но мне его надо еще написать, потому он будет чуть позже. За это время может быть кто-то еще дельного скажет :)

Comment: Спасибо! Только напиши в **ответах**, а не в комментариях ... **=)**

Comment: Естественно... Сюда и не уместится )

Comment: Ты там скоро? А то мне идти через десять минут!

Comment: Если что, я приму ответ вечером... Все равно спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что для решения задачки можно немного изменить подход и сделать его лучше, удобнее и универсальнее. Конечно, свой движок писать не будем, а попробуем решить задачку быстрее и проще.

Итак, имеем, форма, на которой расположена какая-то карта (скрин в вопросе), по карте должна ездить машинка, причем ездить она должна только по дороге, не выезжая за её пределы. Машинка находится в компоненте PictureBox.

Значит, задача сводится к тому, что бы проверять, выехал ли наш PictureBox с машинкой за пределы дороги или нет. Т.е. проверять координаты машинки, и, если при изменении координат машинки при движении они выходят за пределы дороги, то не давать им изменяться, тем самым возвращая машину на путь истинный, т.е. на дорогу.

Возникает вопрос - а как понять, что является дорогой, а что не является?
А тут возникает 2 как минимум 2 подхода на вскидку:

**Способ один.** Анализ цвета.

Дорога у нас серого цвета, все остальное - не серого, просто можем смотреть цвет точки в которую сместится машина, и если он серый, то разрешать смещение, если не серый, то запрещать изменение координат. Разумеется, цвет разметки мы тоже должны учесть.

Плюс тут в том, что мы можем нарисовать практически любую карту с дорогой (почти) любой сложности и машинка будет ездить по дороге.

Минусы вытекают из плюсов, а именно - мы должны учитывать как минимум 2 цвета - разметку и асфальт. И, если дальше мы захотим сделать асфальт [красивее](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82&newwindow=1&safe=off&biw=1280&bih=895&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD95POw7nQAhVGVRoKHalPC_oQ_AUIBigB#newwindow=1&safe=off&tbm=isch&q=%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&imgrc=0VpnENQ5nz_8TM%3A), и нарисовать его многоцветной текстурой, то получится слушком много всяких проверок по цветам.
Еще этот подход плох тем, как мне кажется, что если вдруг автор карты нарисует дорогу или тропинку уже, чем машина, то заехать на такую дорогу по идее тоже нельзя (машина не проходит по ширине), а по факту не исключается и такое. И будут артефакты при движении.
Что бы такого не было, придется делать кучу дополнительных проверок, по ширине и высоте машины, например.

**Способ два.** Массив проходимости.

Второй способ  - тайлы. Не совсем тайлы в [классическом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) понимании, а, скорее, вирутальные тайлы.
Т.е. нашу прямоугольную карту мы разобьем на меньшие прямоугольные области, например, в оригинале размер карты составляет 800 х 600 пикселей, и, если разбить карту на сеточку, допустим 5 х 5 пикселей, то получим что-то навроде листа в клетку, размером 160 х 120 клеточек.
Если представить клетки в виде двумерного массива, например, типа `byte`, например, так:

```
byte[,] map = new byte[160,120]();
```

То мы сможем задать условие проходимости. Например, заполнив весь массив нулями, получим, что он проходим и машинка может ездить.

Но, если, к примеру, мы в коде напишем так: `map[100,100] = 1;`, то скажем, что клетка размером 5х5 (можно хоть 1 х 1 или напротив, большего размера, скажем, 20 х 20) пикселей с виртуальными координатами x = 100, y = 100 не проходима. Реальные координаты получаются умножением виртуальных на размер "тайла" (в нашем случае это 5), т.е. реальное положение тайла будет начинаться в точке с координатами 500 х 500. И занимать прямоугольник с координатами правой нижней точки x = 505, y = 505. Вот эти координаты и нужно будет проверять при движении машинки, еще до отрисовки ёё движения.

В целом, конечно, этот подход тоже обладает кучей минусов (у нас укрупнился масштаб, и чем больше размер тайла, например, не 5 х 5, а 20 х 20, тем угловатее будет карта), нам нужно как-то задавать области проходимых мест на карте, при этом что бы они совпадали с рисунком, и т.д. И плюсы тоже есть )

И это, кстати, далеко не единственный способы по организации движения машинки. 
К слову, есть сходная задача и ее описание [тут](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=230883).

Есть еще в целом описание способов движения персонажей (пусть машинки) в этой [статье на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164489/) ([часть 2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164563/), [часть 3](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164625/)), и с примерами кода, правда, на C++, но он вполне понятен.

Лично сам бы делал по способу №2.

[Вот тут](http://artistweb.ru/blog/different/study/my-first-game-in-c-and-windows-forms.html) - есть готовый пример реализации способа №2 с описанием. Смотрите, изучайте, может быть, достаточно будет просто немного изменить этот пример, что бы получить желаемый результат.

Comment: Пожалуйста, очень рад, что заработало!