# Очистка PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Возможна ли очистка PictureBox, и, если да, то как она производится. С загрузкой изображения все более или менее понятно:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users/Daniil_2/Desktop/car2.png");
```

Но как же очистить PictureBox? Не вставить туда чистый белый рисунок, а именно очистить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
pictureBox1.Image = null;
```

Если вдруг это не срабатывает, то есть такой вариант:

```
pictureBox1.InitialImage = null;
```

Альтернативный способ:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
   {
       pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
       pictureBox1.Image = null;
   }
```

Comment: По [другому вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/593728/222168) всё лучше там обсуждать в комментах.